# How to set correct $key=>$value association in a JSON file using PHP or jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I need to reformat my JSON file so that a value that's in an array, is now the key to that array.

Turn

```
{
    "ID": "M-420",
    "ProductName": "example product name ",
    "ProductDescription": "example description",
    "Color": "blue "
},
{
    "ID": "M-421",
    "ProductName": "example product name ",
    "ProductDescription": "example description",
    "Color": "yellow "
}
```

Into

```
{
    "M-420": {
        "ProductName": "example product name ",
        "ProductDescription": "example description",
        "Color": "blue "
    }
},
{
    "M-421": {
        "ProductName": "example product name ",
        "ProductDescription": "example description",
        "Color": "blue "
    }
}
```

I need to be able to grab the properties of each unique ID using PHP. I'm converting my JSON into an associative array using `$json_decode();`

Much appreciated!

Comment: yes, thank you, I left out the rest of my JSON and forgot to remove the trailing commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple solution would be this:

```
$json_obj_old = json_decode($json_before_process);
$json_obj_new = array();
foreach($json_obj_old as $json_element){
  $json_obj_new[$json_element['ID']] = $json_element;
  unset($json_obj_new[$json_element['ID']]['ID']);
}
return json_encode($json_obj_new);
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked well for what I needed. +1 to @Barmar for assisting as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array as $element) {
    $new_array[$element['ID']] = $element;
}
```

Comment: `unset($new_array[$element['ID']]['ID']);` to exactly replicate the question.

Comment: Yeah, I could do that. But there's no reason to delete useful information, so I chose to leave it in, even though it doesn't exactly match the question.